# The implementation of the game on Iphone

Tags: iphone, frame

I will implement a game in which the ball must move across the screen, and its board should reflect that.
Example: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blocksclassic/id286136632?mt=8

Only in my case the board in the shape of a trapezoid

[image]

If the ball hits the side of the trapeze, he should rebound in the direction of 180 degrees.
Which way do I implement it?

Thank you in advance if you need something clarified please ask questions.

Comment: why do you post an url of a google search? didn't you preview or at least review your post? why don't you have a user name? are you a spam bot?

Comment: sorry for the link from Google. I am not a spam bot

Comment: Users with the name 'user111111' have not set a username since registration with their OpenID. As a >2 year old member, you should know this.

Comment: @Krypton: But I think I remember having typed it in explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can point you in the direction of Cocos2D for iphone, it has bridges to good physics and uses the device functionality quite well.

But in future please try being more specific in your questions...